# use awk to execute logrotate command when disk is full

Tags: logrotate, awk

What I'm trying to do is manually run logrotate when my disk is greater than 90% full. I'm trying to do this using df -P and awk. I can get it to display the percentage, if it's > 90, but I can't quite figure out how to get awk to run logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/ if it's > 90.

Here's what I have that works so far:

Printing the percentage if it's > 90:
      df -P /dev/sda2 | tail -1 | awk '$5 > 90 {print $5}'

Trying to run logrotate

```
  df -P /dev/sda2 | tail -1 | awk '$5 > 90 {system(logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.d) /dev/sda2}'
  df -P /dev/sda2 | tail -1 | awk '$5 > 90 {logrotate -f}'
```

I'm new to all of this, so the exact command would be greatly appreciated. My intent is to put this into a shell script, or as the command portion of a daily cron job.

Thanks for the help.
Patrick.

Answer (score 1):

You were close: the `system` function requires a string

```
awk '$5 > 90 {system("logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.d")}'
```

[reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html#index-system_0028_0029-function)

Comment: Thanks. That works. If I wanted to add that to a crontab, would something like [code]@daily ' df -P /dev/sda2 | tail -1 | awk '$5 > 90 {logrotate -f}'df -P /dev/sda2 | tail -1 | awk '$5 > 90 {logrotate -f}'[/code] (without the "") work?

Comment: No. you need the quotes as shown. Cron is not that magical that it changes how awk works.

Comment: So my cron job would say @daily 'df -P /dev/sda2 | tail -1 | awk '$5 > 90 {logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d}' ?

Comment: You seem determined to not understand what I wrote: `@daily df -P /dev/sda2 | tail -1 | awk '$5 > 90 {system("logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.d")}'`

Comment: I'd love to claim it was a severe lack of sleep, but it really wasn't. I was thinking that in order to make the cron work, I'd have to surround the entire command with quotes as well. Thank you for your patience and help.